# CocoaPods not installing component

Tags: cocoapods

I'm trying to get cocoapods to install JTCalendar and I put the following line in the podfile:

```
pod 'JTCalendar', '~> 2.0'
```

Then, I run pod install and it installp the other components that are already installed in the project, but it does not install JTCalender. 
Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: can you post your Podfile ?

Comment: Can you post the log message of pod update --verbose?

Comment: Actually, I sorted it out... it was just a stupid mistake on my part :p